How can I reduce the frame rate in a swiftUI app?
I'm looking to optimize battery performance by reducing the frame rate to 1hz. The app is a dashboard that updates only once per second, doesn't have animations and is not interactive. Is it possible to set the refresh rate of the OLED display to 1hz?
I tried setting a CADisplayLink in the app delegate but it didn't make a difference.
Apple mentions using this approach in WWDC 2022, but I just can get it to work in my SwiftUI app.

If you post the actual code you tried, someone might be able to help fix it.

The refresh rate is a function of the entire screen. You cannot unilaterally control it yourself. Other things on the screen that are not your app (the status bar, the dynamic island) may need to update. Different screen technologies also require different minimum refresh rates in order to keep a sharp image. None of this is under your app's control.
The minimum refresh rate for ProMotion displays, the common technology for higher-end Pro/Max devices, is 10Hz. I don't know of any iPhone or iPad screen that supports a 1Hz refresh rate.
Your best way to optimize screen refresh performance in SwiftUI is to not invalidate any Views unnecessarily. The OS will tune the refresh rate based on that. If you are using SwiftUI and not invalidating your Views unnecessarily, then I would expect it to run at 10Hz on a ProMotion phone. I believe I've seen 10Hz on my non-ProMotion devices as well, but it's been a while since I audited it.
You only need to employ CADisplayLink if you are doing your own custom rendering. You should avoid this if possible, but Apple gives you tools if you need them. For your situation (pure SwiftUI), the entire answer is "don't invalidate your Views more often then required." There is nothing else you can or should do.

Thank you for your answer. What's odd is that I don't have any animations, I'm updating the state once per second and I'm using an iPhone with ProMotion. The frame rate is stuck at 60fps. When I switch to Low Power mode, it drops to 10fps. I'm trying to replicate the Low Power mode behavior without having to turn it on.

I get the desire and it makes sense. But it may be a choice Apple has made for the user that you can't fix. One thing you might try is making your app full screen. (.fullScreenCover might help here). It's possible that the status bar or dynamic island are requesting faster updates. You might also experiment with manual rendering fullscreen (maybe MetalKit) to see if you can get the refresh you want, and then explore how to put your SwiftUI view inside of that (something like https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/using_metal_to_draw_a_view_s_contents). I don't know if it'll work.

Good point! I'll give that a try.
